# Necessary and Sufficient for existence of extension to the interior for a Holder continuous function defined on a closed curve.

Tags: complex-analysis

$\Gamma$ is a closed smooth curve curve with no self-intersection and let $D$ be its interior. $f:\Gamma \to \mathbb{C}$ is a Holder-continuous function. I want to show the followings are equivalent:

1. There exists a function which coincides with $f$ on $\Gamma$ and is holomorphic in $D$ and continuous in $cl(D)$.
2. $\int_{\Gamma} f(\zeta) \zeta^k d\zeta =0 \space\space
       \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

2 $\to$ 1 seems to be viable by defining a new function using Cauchy's formula. But I don't have any thoughts on the other direction.